# ¿Como puedo obtener el valor actualizado del dolar en android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Soy nuevo en android studio y no logro dar con la forma de hacerlo. En mi PC escribí un script de Bash que hace lo que necesito:

```
#!/bin/sh
wget www.bna.com.ar -O bna 2> /dev/null
cat bna | grep td | grep [0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]| head -2 | tail -1 | cut -d\> -f2 | cut -d\< -f1 | sed 's/,/./' > dolar.txt
rm bna
cat dolar.txt
```

¿Cómo podría implementar esto en Android Studio?

Comment: El titulo no corresponde con lo que en realidad deseas, te sugiero revisar [ask] para que obtengas buenas respuestas, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar este página: http://free.currencyconverterapi.com

para usar su api tienes que usar algo como esto: http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=EUR_USD&compact=ultra

que retorna: `{"EUR_USD":1.199058}`

si lo quieres en pesos argentinos por ejemplo, seria: http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=USD_ARS&compact=ultra

Y bueno, para implementarlo en la app, puedes usar volley (una libreria para realizar peticiones http). Puedes realizar el siguiente tutorial : [Realizar Peticiones Http Con La Librería Volley En Android](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/02/android-volley-peticiones-http/). Pero básicamente es la siguiente:

```
String URL_BASE = "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q=USD_ARS&compact=ultra";
jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
    Request.Method.GET,
    URL_BASE,
    null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //Aquí haces el manejo de la respuesta...
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error Respuesta en JSON: " + error.getMessage());

        }
    }
);
```

Comment: y como lo implementaría en android?. Revisar [answer].